# I can't go from one Tkinter python file to another Tkinter python file again and again, repeatedly

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't go from one Tkinter python file to another Tkinter python file again and again, repeatedly. This is stopping after some tries. First it is going from login --> logout --> login --> then ending.

login.py

```
import tkinter as tk

def click_me():
    root.destroy()
    import logout

# Create the root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a label widget
label = tk.Label(root, text="Login")

# Create a button widget
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=click_me)

# Pack the widgets into the root window
label.pack()
button.pack()

# Start the mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

logout.py

```
import tkinter as tk

def click_me():
    root.destroy()
    import login

# Create the root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a label widget
label = tk.Label(root, text="Logout")

# Create a button widget
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=click_me)

# Pack the widgets into the root window
label.pack()
button.pack()

# Start the mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create new buttons with new functions for logging in/logging out. Inside those functions you can use `import login`/`import logout` to run the code from the other file. Also I recommend that you look at some tutorials on python basics.

Comment: This is an unusual way to write a tkinter program. Why do you need to continuously kill and recreate the root window?

Comment: @BryanOakley, if I don't kill it, the login file will continue to show its interface, which I don't want.

Comment: You don't need to kill and recreate the root window. Tkinter allows  you to create multiple windows. It would likely be easier to initially hide the root window and show a popup for logging in.

Comment: @RanojaySikdar My bad, I didn't see the import statements that you had there. The reason you can't go back is because when python imports a library more than once, the code is only runs the first time.you can add `importlib.reload(login)`/`importlib.reload(logout)` after the 2 import statements. Make sure you first `import importlib` in both files.